# DEFINING and NON-DEFINING RELATIVE CLAUSES?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentences below is/are grammatical?

SENTENCE 1: This is the bread that you gave me, ***that*** is sold at ABC bakery.

SENTENCE 2: This is the bread that you gave me ***that*** is sold at ABC bakery.

SENTENCE 3: This is the bread that you gave me, ***which*** is sold at ABC bakery.

Comment: Is it true that we can't use two defining relative clauses in one sentence and that following relative clauses should be or will always be non-defining?

Comment: No, that is not true. 'Stacking' is possible with defining relatives, but not with non-defining ones. "That" cannot normally be used in non-defining relatives, so 1. is ungrammatical. 2. and 3. are grammatically possible: 2. is correct if the relative clause is defining, 3. if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Non-defining relative clauses give additional information to your sentence. This information is not necessary to understand who or what is being referred to. We do need commas around non-defining relative clauses in a sentence.

Therefore, the third sentence is preferable.

> This is the bread that you gave me, which is sold at ABC bakery.

You can remove the clause [which is sold at ABC bakery] and the sentence still makes sense.

However, defining relative clauses do not need commas. Here are some examples of defining relative clauses:

> The lady who teaches me English is from Britain.
>
> The English course which I have chosen lasts for 10 weeks.
>
> The book that we are learning grammar from is really helpful.

You can find out more about relative clauses in this blog post: https://intrepidenglish.co.uk/relative-clauses/

Let me know if you have any questions and best of luck with your studies.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked: Are the three sentences grammatical? Also, promoting your personal commercial website is not in the spirit of this community - there are far more authoritative references that could have been given.

Answer (score 1):

If the second clause is nonrestrictive, i.e. you didn't give me breads from multiple bakeries, it takes a comma, and #2 is faulted. Following the recommended practice of using "which" for nonrestrictive clauses, #3 is best.

If restrictive, i.e. multiple breads and bakeries, then #2 is correct.